# The character array doesn't work in file handling

Tags: c, arrays, file-io

What i was trying to do is, create a program that asks the user to enter how much long text he want to write. And after than whatever he writes in the console gets automatically saved in a textfile named `file` at following path mentioned in the code. So, to ask user the size of character array i used `int i`. And then used `gets` command to pick up whatever he wrote as it is with spaces and other characters. But the code doesn't seem to work it asks the user about how many character and then runs complete and terminates. Also tell me what should do to make it create a new file in `Data` folder everytime user starts the program? I don't want to overwrite the existing file or append text to it. I want to create a new file and let the user name it whatever he feels like and then store that text in that new file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
FILE *file = fopen("C://Users//Abhimanyu Aryan//Desktop//Data//Hello.txt", "w");

printf("\t\tThis program allows you to write detailed data\n\n\n");

int c;
printf("you many characters file you want to write? Specify: ");
scanf("%i",&c);

printf("\n\nEnter your text here: ");

char text[c];

gets(text);


fprintf(file, "%s" , text);

printf(" the file has been written succesfully!!!!");

fclose(file);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Please look up "gets" and "scanf" in your c-documentation.
Also enable compilation warnings, probably "-w all", and look up why they complain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with your code. First, you should check the return value from `fopen()` to make sure everything was successful:

```
FILE *file = fopen("C://Users//Abhimanyu Aryan//Desktop//Data//Hello.txt", "w");
if (file == NULL) {
    /* Handle fopen() error */
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open file for writing!");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

The second mistake is that you are using `gets()`. `gets()` **is old, deprecated and unsafe, you should never use it**. Use `fgets()` instead:

```
char text[c];

fgets(text, sizeof text, stdin);
```

If you want the user to choose the filename, it's a matter of asking him first, and then open the specified filename for writing. If the file doesn't exist, it will automatically be created:

```
#define MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH 128

char filename[MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH];
printf("Enter filename (max. %zu characters): ", sizeof(filename)-1);
fgets(filename, sizeof filename, stdin);

FILE *file = fopen(filename, "w");
if (file == NULL) {
    /* Handle fopen() error as mentioned above*/
}
```

**UPDATE**:

Note that `scanf("%i", &c);` will leave a newline on the buffer (from when you press the ENTER key). That's why `fgets()` is returning prematurely without waiting: it reads a newline left on the buffer from the previous input and assumes you're done (`fgets` stops when it hits a newline). To fix it, you have to consume the buffered newline before calling `scanf()`. You can do so with `getchar()`, for example:

```
/* ... */
scanf("%i",&c);
/* Consume newline left on buffer from scanf */
if (getchar() == '\r')
    (void) getchar();
printf("\n\nEnter your text here: ");
/* ... */
```

The `if (gethcar() == '\r')` is there to make the code work in the case that `stdin` was redirected to a file with DOS end-of-lines (`\r\n` rather than only `\n`), in which case 2 characters must be consumed. Even if you plan to use this from the terminal only (without `stdin` redirecton), I would still recommend leaving it that way - pressing ENTER might push `\r\n` to `stdin` too.

Comment: i think the error here i am getting is for:

char text[c].....i am supplying variable here if i give a fixed size to char text. Code works fine char text[100]

Comment: @user3411392 Which compiler are you using? Variable-length arrays are supported since C99.

Comment: This is the file when i pass a variable for array size: http://i1313.photobucket.com/albums/t557/cooldudeabhi/asd_zpsd7d33617.png

This is when i pass a constant size to array: http://i1313.photobucket.com/albums/t557/cooldudeabhi/new_zpsf9679577.png

Please help :(

Comment: @user3411392 Found the problem. See my updated answer. The problem was not related with the variable size - it just happened to work with a constant because you commented the `scanf()` call. `scanf()` leaves the newline character buffered, so `fgets()` was returning prematurely.

Comment: What do you mean by reading newline? why does this happen? when will it happen? where does this newline add?

Also please explain these two code 
printf("Enter filename (max. %zu characters): ",sizeof(filename)-1);

what is (max. %zu character): here?

and what is this (void)getchar (); doing

Comment: @user3411392 Generally, `scanf()` format specifiers do not consume newlines (there are a few exceptions). `%d` (or, for that matter, `%i`) reads an integer. A newline is not part of an integer, so it is not read. It stays buffered until the next read operation *that can consume it* takes place. This is hard to explain in a single comment. If you really want to undertand `scanf()` behaviour, I **strongly** suggest to read my article about it on my blog: http://codinghighway.com/?p=422 - it's a bit lengthy, but if you take the time to read it, I promise you will understand :p

Comment: @user3411392 About the `%zu`: this is a format specifier to print integers of type `size_t`, which is the type of the result of `sizeof` operator.

Answer (score 0):

I would change

```
FILE *file = fopen("C://Users//Abhimanyu Aryan//Desktop//Data//Hello.txt", "w");
```

to

```
FILE *file = fopen("C:/Users/Abhimanyu Aryan/Desktop/Data/Hello.txt", "w");
```

or

```
FILE *file = fopen("C:\\Users\\Abhimanyu Aryan\\Desktop\\Data\\Hello.txt", "w");
```

I don't know that having two forward slashes as directory separator causes any problems but it is certainly not necessary.